# C# Run VB.net Assembly from Bytes

Tags: c#, vb.net, memory, assemblies

I am using this code, I got it to work fine with any C# assembly that allows it to be ran from memory. Is there anyway I could get it to work with VB.net?

```
    private static void RunFromMemory()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                bytes = client.DownloadData(new Uri("http://example.com/program.exe"));
            }
            Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
            exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

The error I receive is "Parameter count mismatch"

Comment: Is the question how do I convert this code to VB.Net code?

Comment: No, I would like to know how I can use this code to run VB.net Assemblies. Right now it only works for C# assemblies.

Comment: I'd have thought that both VB.NET and C# assemblies would result in approximately the same MSIL... is there something different between them such as framework version? Or perhaps if they are a Console or UI target, etc.

Comment: I tested it with a Windows Form Application VB.net with .NET Framework 3.5 and it didn't work.

Comment: This is still not making sense.  Did you try to run this CODE using the VB.NET compiler, or did you compile this code into a DLL and try to reference the DLL from C#? How, exactly, are you tying to do this?  (This might be one of those situations where someone needs to see what you're attempting to be able to explain why it's not working.)

Comment: @David Stratton Basically, it is in one of my projects right now, my client for my site(C# Windows Form Application). And for safety of my C# applications I use this and run them from memory. This only works for C# assemblies for some reason. I want to be able to have this work to run VB.net assemblies from memory.

Comment: Can you describe the error you receive or what happens exactly? You may need to not swallow the exception, if one is occurring.

Comment: The error I receive is "Parameter count mismatch"

Comment: The solution is down this page ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Loadr
    ' by Zibri at zibri dot org
    Private Sub Loadr_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim t = New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf launcher))
        t.Start()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub launcher()
        Dim prog As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("programtorun.exe")
        Dim asm As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(prog)

        asm.EntryPoint.Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {New String() {"argument1","argument2"}})
    End Sub

End Class
```

Obviously the loading from a file is just as an example. Just fill "b" with the file you need to run.